# Comment object implied through association is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, null

So I have a User and Comment model. I am in the process of implementing a rating system for the comments, such that we can keep track of who has already voted on a particular comment. I thought of making another class (who_rated_comment_rel) to describe the relationship that is created when a user rates a comment. I am doing Test Driven Development so I am writing my tests first. However I had this issue that I had been working on for several hours now, but I can't seem to get past it. Below are the relevant code, and the most important parts are *emphasized.*

```
rspec spec/model 
gives me the following error:

**Failures:**

 1) WhoRatedCommentRel follower methods comment 
 Failure/Error: its(:comment) { should eq comment }

   expected: #<Comment id: 4, created_at: "2013-09-21 00:28:44", updated_at: "2013-09-21 00:28:44", usr_id: 4, upd_id: 4, com_id: 4, content: "Lorem Ipsum", rating: nil, who_rated: nil>
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/who_rated_comment_rel_spec.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

...

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/who_rated_comment_rel_spec.rb:21 # WhoRatedCommentRel follower methods comment
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar123"
        password_confirmation "foobar123"

        factory :admin do
        admin true
        end
    end

    factory :comment do
        sequence(:usr_id) { |n| n }
        sequence(:upd_id) { |n| n }
        sequence(:com_id) { |n| n }

        content "Lorem Ipsum"

        factory :usr_1 do
        usr_id 1
        end

    factory :usr_2 do
        usr_id 2
    end

    factory :upd_1 do
        upd_id 1
    end

    factory :upd_2 do
        upd_id 2
    end


    end

    factory :pin do 
        description "Build the next Facebook"
        user
    end
end
```

**spec/models/who_rated_comment_rel_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe WhoRatedCommentRel do
    let(:user)    { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:comment) { FactoryGirl.create(:comment) }
    let(:voting_rel) do
    user.who_rated_comment_rels.build(comment_id: comment.id) 
end

subject { voting_rel }

it { should be_valid }


describe "follower methods" do

    it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
    it { should respond_to(:comment_id) }
    its(:comment) { should eq comment }
    its(:user)    { should eq user }
  end
end
```

**app/models/who_rated_comment_rel.rb**

```
class WhoRatedCommentRel < ActiveRecord::Base
    *belongs_to :user,    class_name: "User"*
    *belongs_to :comment, class_name: "Comment"* 
end
```

**app/models/comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :usr_id, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true
    validates :upd_id, presence: true

    attr_accessible :usr_id, :content, :upd_id

    def upvote 

    end

    def downvote

    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

    validates :name, presence: true, 
                 uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                 length: { maximum: 30 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy
    *has_many :who_rated_comment_rels, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy*
```

**GEMFILE**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'haml'

gem 'simple_form', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
gem 'devise'
gem 'protected_attributes'

gem 'sass-rails',   '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier',         '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1' # for testing.
    gem 'debugger'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end 

group :production do 
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Please post your factories.rb file.

Comment: We're you trying to emphasize the `belongs_to` and `has_many` lines in your code using the "emphasis" character `*`? If so, the code listing don't take markup (as far as I know). In any event, is your `User` model really defined in your `comment.rb` file?

Comment: I just ran your spec file successfully with a bare bones definition `User`, `Comment` and `WhoRatedCommentRel` and it worked fine (with the `User` class defined in it's own file).  Does you test schema have the `who_rated_comment_rels` table defined with the `user_id` and `comment_id` fields?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, folks.

The issue was that I am still using *protected_attributes* gem, and passing the comment.id into the new instance of the relationship didn't allow me due to me not making rated_comment_id *attr_accessible*. Unfortunately RSpec didn't complain about the mass-assignment issue. I only figured it out when inputing the same commands into the rails console (sandboxed).